# Drupal 7 custom logo in page.tpl.php not displaying on all pages

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a Drupal 7 site with a custom sub theme based on Zen.  I have a custom logo that I placed in the page.tpl.php header div.  The problem I'm having is that the logo only shows up on the first "main" pages, but not "subpages".  Excuse my terminology here trying to explain this.  What I mean by subpages is any page that is further down the chain or occurring after the first forward slash.  Below is an example of what I mean by "main" pages and "subpages".  All these "main" pages are directly after the first slash after the website name.  The logo doesn't show up on any pages that occur after these main pages (subpages). All my pages are made using the Pages module, however, the subpages have a path using %term, for example /support/%term or products/%term.

What am I missing and what do I need to do to make my logo in page.tpl.php show up on all pages of my site? Am I supposed to create a new page.tpl.php file for the pages using /%term?

Main pages - logo shows up:

```
mysite.com/about 
mysite.com/products 
mysite.com/support    
mysite.com/contact
```

Sub pages - logo doesn't show up:

```
mysite.com/products/product1
mysite.com/support/product1-support
```

Comment: I think you are loading some other tpl,php page. Try to write a print_r() or kpr() if devel is installed in page.tpl.php to check whether you are loading the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the quick fix for that is to make sure your logo's path starts with '/', like so:

```
<img src="/sites/all/themes/customZen/images/logo.png" />
```

But then if path of the theme changes everything will break, so don't do this.

If you place the logo using CSS as a background, use relative URL (it is relative to the path of .css file)

Or you can do something like this in your page.tpl.php:

```
<img src="<?php url($directory . '/images/logo.png'); ?>" />
```

**$directory** is the directory the template is located in, e.g. sites/all/themes/customZen.

Full list of page.tpl.php variables can be found here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7.x

Comment: When I change the path to start with '/' it made the logo disappear on all the pages.  The other fix didn't work either.

Comment: You say "I have a custom logo that I placed in the page.tpl.php header div" -
 could you post your code for that then?
Also inspecting the logo element on the pages where it's broken using browser's inspector tool may provide a clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: The page.tpl.php is working for all pages because I placed some test text in the page.tpl.php header and it shows up so this leads me to believe that it's the path of the logo that's not working for these internal pages.  It's strange how the logo shows up on all the main pages, but not the internal ones (those having more than one slash - mysite.com/products/product-1 for example).

Comment: The path to my logo in the header of page.tpl.php is this: sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/logo.png   This path is wrapped in a logo div. I tried putting a forward slash in front of "sites" at the beginning of the path, but it causes the logo to not show up on any pages at all. When I inspect the page with the inspector tool I can see the logo div there, but it's just missing the logo.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help with this.

Comment: Do you know how I can change the path for the inner pages so it works?

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this?..Well, if you didn't, try with this in your page.tpl.php paste this:

```html
<img alt="" src="<?php echo drupal_get_path('theme', 'customZen');?>/images/logo.png">
```

Good luck!